# Setting environment variable in kubernetes stateful set

Tags: kubernetes, configmap, statefulset

I have configmap with data myapp-0:VALUE_A and myapp-1:VALUE_B. In a statefull set with 2 pods myapp-0 and myapp-1 I need to set environment myapp-0=VALUE_A for pod "myapp-0" and myapp-1=VALUE_B for pod myapp-1

I am not able fetch the key dynamically from configmap using $(POD_ORDINAL)

Comment: you cannot do that since the container-temaplte most be identical for the instances of the StatefulSet.

Comment: The value returned by `hostname` will have a predictable format, though, and you could use this to do a lookup in ConfigMap data mounted as files.